# Optimize deletion query for duplicate rows in SQLite3?

Tags: sql, database, performance, sqlite

I'm trying to delete one of the duplicate rows with the highest user ID in my table, consisting of 3.5 million rows. I have around 1300 rows to delete, and I am currently using the following query:

```
delete from Data
where exists (select 1 from Data t2
              where data.code = t2.code and data.issue = t2.issue
                and data.id < t2.id);
```

The query has run for more than 15 minutes. Is there any way I can optimize this to decrease the time taken? I'm using SQLite version 3.22.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, deleting a lot of rows in a table is simply inefficient.  It can be faster to reconstruct the table.

The idea is to select the rows you want into another table:

```
create table temp_data as
    select t.*
    from data t
    where t.id = (select max(t2.id)
                  from data t2
                  where t2.code = t.code and t2.issue = t.issue
                 );
```

For this query, you want an index on `(code, issue, id)`.

Then when the data is safely tucked away and validated, you can empty the existing table and re-insert:

```
delete from data;
```

Be sure you have removed any triggers on the table.  You can read about SQLite's "truncate" optimization in the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).  In most other databases, you would use the command `truncate table data`.

Then, you can re-insert the data:

```
insert into data
    select *
    from temp_data;
```

Comment: 1300 rows out of 3.5 million are not a lot of rows.