# Optimize deletion of one of duplicate rows with highest user ID or rowid in SQLite3?

Tags: sql, database, performance, sqlite

I'm having some trouble with deleting duplicate rows that either belongs to a) the same user or b) different users.

For case a) I want to delete one of the duplicate rows, and for case b) I want to delete the row with the highest user ID.

**Example**

In the table below, I have 2 duplicate rows, one with code A and issue 1; one with code B and issue 1. Code B is "owned" by 2 different users, and I want to delete user 2 in this case, as they have the highest user ID.

For the rows with code A; I want to delete one of those rows. Since they are identical, I just want 1 copy of the row.

```
+--------+------+-------+
| UserID | Code | Issue |
+--------+------+-------+
| 1      | A    | 1     |
+--------+------+-------+
| 1      | A    | 1     |
+--------+------+-------+
| 1      | B    | 1     |
+--------+------+-------+
| 2      | B    | 1     |
+--------+------+-------+
```

**Wanted Result**

```
+--------+------+-------+
| UserID | Code | Issue |
+--------+------+-------+
| 1      | A    | 1     |
+--------+------+-------+
| 1      | B    | 1     |
+--------+------+-------+
```

I've previously attempted to use:

```
create table temp_data as
    select t.*
    from data t
    where t.id = (select max(t2.id)
                  from data t2
                  where t2.code = t.code and t2.issue = t.issue
                 );
```

As part of step 1 of the [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65970684/optimize-deletion-query-for-duplicate-rows-in-sqlite3), but was not able to handle case a). What can I do to handle case a) of duplicate rows?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas Examples and expected results added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your table does not seem to have a `PRIMARY KEY`, you can use the column [`rowid`](https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) and the column `UserID` to decide which rows will be deleted:

```
DELETE FROM Data
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Data d 
  WHERE d.Code = Data.Code AND d.Issue = Data.Issue 
  AND (d.rowid < Data.rowid OR d.UserID < Data.UserID)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e3a0d3a356afdc26ae69daff8b6dc38c).
.
Results:

| UserID | Code | Issue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 1 |